# my code is running well during execution...but i when i go to submit its show segmentation fault

Tags: c++

Given an array C of size N-1 and given that there are numbers from 1 to N with one element missing, the missing number is to be found.

Input:

The first line of input contains an integer T denoting the number of test cases. For each test case first line contains N(size of array). The subsequent line contains N-1 array elements.

Output:

Print the missing number in array.

Constraints:

1 ≤ T ≤ 200

1 ≤ N ≤ 107

1 ≤ C[i] ≤ 107

Example:

Input:

```
2
5
1 2 3 5
10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 10
```

Output:

```
4
9
```

i have done this in c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
int a,n,arr[50],j=1,element;
int sum,total[50],i;
cin>>n;
a=n;
while(n!=0)
{
    cin>>element;
    sum=0;
    total[j]=0;
    for(i=1;i<=element-1;i++)
    {
        cin>>arr[i];
        sum=sum+arr[i];
    }
    total[j]=(element*(element+1)/2) -sum;
    j++;
    n--;
}
for(i=1;i<=a;i++)
{
    cout<<total[i]<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
4
9
```

Comment: Look at the constraints, and look at the sizes of the arrays you declared, and I think you'll see the problem.

Comment: Nice way to solve the problem BTW, although you don't need the `total` array. Just output each result as you get it, instead of putting them all in an array and outputting them at the end.

Comment: If `n` is 50 or more, `total[j]` will perform access beyond the array limit... Indexing in C starts from 0.

Comment: Why have you included "python" tag ??

Comment: @VishalSrivastav I've deleted python and C

Answer (score 0):

Because you have declared the array of size 50 blocks.

But , according to given constraints : 1 ≤ N ≤ 107  ,  1 ≤ C[i] ≤ 107

if you take value of element more than 50 , it will give segmentation fault because the maximum size of array is 50.

So , increase the size of arrays to **arr[107];** and **total[107];**

And then submit the solution , it would work then.

Comment: `1 ≤ T ≤ 200` so `total` needs to be `total[201]` given the code as is (or it could just be eliminated)

Comment: i have change peremiter from 50 to 500...thanks to u..i forget to look at constraints now my code is working fine..one problem is their ..while submitting its showing me   Wrong Answer. !!!Wrong Answer
Possibly your code doesn't work correctly for multiple test-cases (TCs).
The first test case where your code failed:

Input:
5
1 2 3 5

Its Correct output is:
4

And Your Code's output is:
501

Answer (score 0):

Try this as a test case:

```
2
55
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55
55
33 54 1 55 23 51 35 5 49 26 43 42 41 32 7 14 9 50 34 29 37 25 52 24 8 53 15 45 44 19 39 47 17 48 38 21 36 31 3 18 46 20 6 27 12 11 16 10 2 13 28 4 30 22
```

your code should then crash under your control, and then you can find out why.

Think hard about the constraints you were given for various values and how your code operates at the edges of those constraints.

Also, there is a way to solve this problem that doesn't require you to use any arrays at all. It's the fastest way to solve the problem.

Comment: and i have run by code its working fine....but while submitting they showed and error...                                                                                                                                  Wrong Answer. !!!Wrong Answer
Possibly your code doesn't work correctly for multiple test-cases (TCs).
The first test case where your code failed:

Input:
5
1 2 3 5

Its Correct output is:
4

And Your Code's output is:
501

Comment: @user11249680 - You actually have the bones of the correct answer in your answer. You're doing a lot more work than you need to.

Answer (score -2):

**One of the best solution for finding Missing element is using XOR operator :**

Question: You are given a list of n-1 integers , And these integers are in the range of 1
 to n. There are no duplicates in the list . One of the integer is missing in the list. 
Now, we need to find that missing number.

Solution :

**Method 1 :** By finding sum of first “n” natural numbers.

Step 1 : First, find the sum of all numbers from 1 to n ( means find the sum of first “n” natural numbers)

Step 2 : Subtract each element (all elements) of the given list from the sum. And we’ll get the missing number.

Note : There might be an integer overflow while adding large numbers in method 1 solution.

**Method 2: Using XOR operator :**

**Remember these properties : n ^ n = 0 AND n ^ 0 = n**

**Step 1: We’ll take the xor of all numbers from 1 to n (Means, we’ll take xor of first “n” natural numbers).**

**Step 2: We’ll take the xor of all elements of the given array (list).**

**Step 3: xor of Step 1 and Step 2 will give the required missing number.**

```
Example : Given list arr = [4,2,1,6,8,5,3,9] n=9 (given)

Step1 : Step1_result = 1 ^ 2 ^ 3 ^ 4 ^ 5 ^ 6 ^ 7 ^ 8 ^ 9 = 1

Step2 : Step2_result = 4 ^ 2 ^ 1 ^ 6 ^ 8 ^ 5 ^ 3 ^ 9 = 6

Step3 : Final_Result = Step1_result ^ Step2_result = 1 ^ 6 = 7

But, How Final_Result calculated the missing number ?

Final_Result= ( 1 ^ 2 ^ 3 ^ 4 ^ 5 ^ 6 ^ 7 ^ 8 ^ 9 ) ^ ( 4 ^ 2 ^ 1 ^ 6 ^ 8 ^ 5 ^ 3 ^ 9 )    

So , here ,

Final_Result = (1 ^ 2 ^ 3 ^ 4 ^ 5 ^ 6 ^ 7 ^ 8 ^ 9 ) ^ ( 4 ^ 2 ^ 1 ^ 6 ^ 8 ^ 5 ^ 3 ^ 9 )

= 1 ^ 2 ^ 3 ^ 4 ^ 5 ^ 6 ^ 7 ^ 8 ^ 9 ^ 4 ^ 2 ^ 1 ^ 6 ^ 8 ^ 5 ^ 3 ^ 9

= ( 1 ^ 1 ) ^ ( 2 ^ 2 ) ^ ( 3 ^ 3 ) ^ ( 4 ^ 4 ) ^ ( 5 ^ 5 ) ^ ( 6 ^ 6 ) ^ (7) ^ ( 8 ^ 8 ) ^ ( 9 ^ 9 )

= 0 ^ 0 ^ 0 ^ 0 ^ 0 ^ 0 ^ 7 ^ 0 ^ 0 ( property applied )

= 0 ^ 7 ( because we know 0 ^ 0 = 0 )

= 000 ^ 111

= 111

= 7 ( Required Result )
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the original poster's question at all. And additionally, just gives the original poster an alternate answer to a problem. This is clearly a problem from some coding problem website. Giving them the answer is the opposite of helpful. The point of those websites is so you can figure out the answer yourself. Lastly, your answer is less efficient than it could be for either method you chose.

Comment: Though the xor method is clever. I'll give you that. Though, given that an alternate set of operations for binary numbers that allows all algebraic operations to work is to use xor for add, the two methods are basically equivalent formulations of the same solution, just using different numeric fields.